# How to make One Search Module for Multiple Tables in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to search for Either 'Professional' or 'Vendor' tables along with 'Users' table.. can you help me out of the query how i have make it possible in one search, to decide where the search belongs.

The below result is looking for matches in tables.. i dont want that.. i want the right match in both individual tables.. can anyone help me ?

```
<?php

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('professional', 'professional.accountId = users.id');
$this->db->join('vendor', 'vendor.accountId = users.id');
$this->db->like('users.realname', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.email', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.category', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.full_name', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.license_id', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.state', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.city', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.country', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.pincode', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.mobile', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.phone', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.profession', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.state', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.city', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.country', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.pincode', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.mobile', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.phone', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.firm_catagory', $search_term);
$this->db->group_by("users.id");

$query = $this->db->get();

$qu = $query->result_array();

foreach ($qu as $row) {

$row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['accountId'])); //build an array
}

echo json_encode($row_set);
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I Found The Answer.. By myself : But i want to print more results like $row['country'] , $row['city'], $row['state'] etc.. )**

```
<?php

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('professional', 'professional.accountId = users.id');
$this->db->like('users.realname', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.email', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.category', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.full_name', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.license_id', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.state', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.city', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.country', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.pincode', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.mobile', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.phone', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('professional.profession', $search_term);
$this->db->group_by("users.id");

$query = $this->db->get();

$qu = $query->result_array();

foreach ($qu as $row) {

$row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['accountId'])); //build an array
}
if (isset($row_set)) {

echo json_encode($row_set);

}




$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('vendor', 'vendor.accountId = users.id');
$this->db->like('users.realname', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.email', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.category', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.full_name', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('users.license_id', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.state', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.city', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.country', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.pincode', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.mobile', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.phone', $search_term);
$this->db->or_like('vendor.firm_catagory', $search_term);
$this->db->group_by("users.id");
$query2 = $this->db->get();
$qu2 = $query2->result_array();

foreach ($qu2 as $row) {

$row_set2[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['accountId'])); //build an array
}

if (isset($row_set2)) {

echo json_encode($row_set2);

}
?>
```